# What does a MySQL "NO SQL" function mean exactly?

Tags: mysql

What does the MySQL "NO SQL" function qualifer mean exactly? Suppose I have this function definition:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION Test() RETURNS text
NO SQL
BEGIN
  DECLARE x TEXT DEFAULT '';
  SET x = CONCAT('X = ', UUID());
  RETURN x;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Is it correct that this should be declared as NO SQL? If not how should it be declared?

If the above should not be declared as "NO SQL", what is an example of such a function?

Comment: Reference says what? If there is one thing MySQL has going for it ... it is the reference. ("Several characteristics provide information about the nature of data use by the routine. In MySQL, these characteristics are advisory only ... NO SQL indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements"). Of course, like good documentation, it should reflect the code.

Comment: Ok, so does the above function contain SQL statements or not?

Comment: @richb No - there are no SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE satements - In Oracle land this would be called PL/SQL only, no SQL is embedded.

Comment: An important doubt here is whether `SET` is considered a SQL statement and it isn't trivial: two answers so far and they disagree about that.

Answer (score 6):

It means that the function or procedure contains no SQL in it.

From the [online docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-procedure.html):

- `NO SQL` indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements.

It's *probably* in there as an optimisation assistance method, allowing the function to be flagged as not requiring processing that would be necessary for SQL. The other options in that group all indicate varying levels of data processing:

- `CONTAINS SQL` indicates that the routine does not contain statements that read or write data. This is the default if none of these characteristics is given explicitly. Examples of such statements are `SET @x = 1` or `DO RELEASE_LOCK('abc')`, which execute but neither read nor write data.
- `NO SQL` indicates that the routine contains no SQL statements.
- `READS SQL DATA` indicates that the routine contains statements that read data (for example, `SELECT`), but not statements that write data.
- `MODIFIES SQL DATA` indicates that the routine contains statements that may write data (for example, `INSERT` or `DELETE`).

These are actually clauses defined by the SQL standard but it's interesting to note another quote from that linked page:

> In MySQL, these characteristics are advisory only. The server does not use them to constrain what kinds of statements a routine will be permitted to execute.

In other words, they don't actually *do* anything in MySQL other than make the language compatible with the standards.

In terms of an example of a function that uses *no* SQL, you may have one that takes a string and returns a hash value for storage into a database later on.

Comment: So what is an example of a function that contains no sql statements?

Comment: The function in your question contains no SQL statements.

Comment: Greg: so you disagree with paxdiablo's description of a "CONTAINS SQL" function then? What would be a function that qualifies as "CONTAINS SQL"?

Comment: @richb, that's not _my_ description, by the way, it's from the official documentation.

Comment: paxdiablo: Ok thanks. I am none the wiser as the comments in this thread are contradictory.

Comment: So  SET is a sql statement but RETURN isn't ?   What are we allowed to use in a NO SQL function ?

Comment: @DavidV.: For MySQL, anything you want. As stated in the answer, in the online docs linked to (5.6) and even the latest online docs (8.0), "In MySQL, these characteristics are advisory only. The server does not use them to constrain what kinds of statements a routine will be permitted to execute. "

Answer (score 3):

The correct definition for your sample function is CONTAINS SQL. The SQL standard permits functions to be in other languages besides SQL, and, for example, a C function containing no SQl would be defined as LANGUAGE C NO SQL.

A C function could also contain non-modifying SQL, and the standard SQL definition would then be LANGUAGE C CONTAINS SQL.

In MySQL, only SQL is supported, so NO SQL exists for the purposes of supporting the standard only.